# Storing common modifiable (by all local users) application settings in Windows C#/C++

Tags: c#, c++, windows, settings

What is the best way to store common application settings in Windows, which are modifiable by all local pc users.

I need to store a file with settings but other users (= local users from the pc, not external users) should also be able to modify these.

You can write items to:

- the registry
- c:\TEMP folder (or just another folder)
- network pipe (too complex)
- Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData
- IsolatedStorage (?)
- etc...

I have been looking at the Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData but other users can only read in this folder and not write.

What is now the recommended/best way to store common application settings modifiable by all local users. (Windows XP should still be supported.)

Does anyone have a full overview of storing and global application settings and their (dis)advantages?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Best place is a share on a file server that's backed-up at least once a day.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand how users can write to the registry/network with writing into a shared file. Do you mean creating a Windows Service that will listen for changes in the file, and will then try to execute some predefined templates from that file? If so - I'm curious how this will handle deletes in the file.

Comment: @Tisho : It is a Windows application that needs to store application settings. Not user specific settings, but settings for all local users on the pc.
By creating a file in the Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData all local users can read the settings but only the file creator can modify it. So I was looking for an alternative where all local users also can modify a file instead of only the creator. Hope this makes something clear.
HansPassant : it is not about creating backups.

Comment: Ahh, makes sense now. How do you create the file? It seems like a write lock problem? What error does the other users get when trying to write in the file?

Comment: You need to change the file permissions after you have created it in CommonApplicationData to allow read/write access for everyone.

Comment: So this should be done first?: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/61987/Allow-write-modify-access-to-CommonApplicationData 

Is using IsolatedStorage not a good solution or is it the same? What is the difference/limitations compared with using the CommonApplicationData+changing permissions?

Comment: @juFo Any updates to this issue? How did you finally solve it?

Comment: @Wolf I didn't, rewrote so that it wouldn't be needed. If you have a suggestion let me know